# HapiJS: Configure the HapiJs API according to the query parameter passed in request?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

My APIs are written in Hapijs. and want to configure the API based on `queryParams` of `request` object.
I have an API with endpoint `/test` and `queryParams` is `type=a` or `type=b`.
If `type` equals `'a'` then I need to pass `false` in `auth` and if the `type` equals `'b'` then I need to pass `true` in `auth`.

```
   {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/media',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            TestModule.getTestData(request.query).then(reply,(err) => {
                reply(err);
            });
        },
        config: {
            description: 'This is the test API',
            notes: 'Returns a message',
            tags: ['api', 'Test'],
            auth: false // Here I need to do something.
        },
    }
```

**Could you please suggest to me what I can do?**

I am doing this:

```
   {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/media',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            TestModule.getTestData(request.query).then(reply,(err) => {
                reply(err);
            });
        },
        config: {
            description: 'This is the test API',
            notes: 'Returns a message',
            tags: ['api', 'Test'],
            auth: request.query.type==='a'?false:true // Here I need to do something.
        },
    }
```

But getting an error `ReferenceError: request is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

Why not just evaluate response.query.type and then redirect based on the type?

```
 {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/media',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        const {
         type
        } = request.query;

        TestModule.getTestData(type).then(reply,(err) => {
            if(type === a) {
             // do something
            }
            //do something else
            reply(err);
        });
    },
    config: {
        description: 'This is the test API',
        notes: 'Returns a message',
        tags: ['api', 'Test'],
        auth: false // Here I need to do something.
    },
}
```

Comment: This is not gonna work for me, Because I need to check the token and then need to verify the token which can increase the response time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an optional/try auth strategy mode.
See https://hapijs.com/api/#-routeoptionsauthmode for details.
What this comes down to is

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/media',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        if (request.query.type !== 'a' && !request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            return reply(Boom.unauthorized('GET /media not allowed'));
        }

        TestModule.getTestData(request.query).then(reply,(err) => {
            reply(err);
        });
    },
    config: {
        description: 'This is the test API',
        notes: 'Returns a message',
        tags: ['api', 'Test'],
        auth: {
            strategy: 'your auth strategy',
            mode: 'try' // depending on your strategy. If you use a already existing strategy you probably want to use try as it will authenticate what it can and then you can still decide what to do in your handler.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please suggest me in details?

Comment: I assume you want to authorize based on `request.query.type` right?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/johnbrett/hapi-auth-bearer-token/tree/v5.1.1 (assuming you are using hapi 16) where you set `allowQueryToken: true` and `accessTokenName: 'type'` and then in the `validateFunc` you can decide what is valid and what not. If you want an example on that I can edit my answer.